# A directive allowing to make a whole DOM subtree readonly

Tags: javascript, performance, angular.js

What do you think about this directive? For each `input`, it traverses the DOM towards the root and if it finds an element with the class `readonly`, it makes the input `readonly`.

An `ng-readonly` directive on the `input` itself get honored: The input becomes readonly whenever `ng-readonly` evaluates to true or any enclosing element has the class `readonly`.

```
.directive("input", function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        link: function($scope, element, attr) {
            if (attr.type === "radio" || attr.type === "checkbox") {
              return; // for simplicity, let's ignore them
            }

            var org = attr.ngReadonly;
            if (!org && attr.readonly) {
              return; // readonly seems to be set manually, so let's not touch it
            }

            $scope.$watch(function() {
                var readonly = $parse(org)($scope);
                for (var e = element; e.length && !readonly; e=e.parent()) {
                    readonly = e.hasClass("readonly");
                }
                console.log(element.attr("ng-model"), readonly)
                attr.$set("readonly", !!readonly);
            });
        },
    };
})
```

The purpose is to allow to make a whole subtree readonly, no matter what's inside. It [works](http://plnkr.co/edit/VRzjU3XWeyhoOoqlq5dC?p=preview), but I can imagine there can be performance problems and/or interferences with `ng-readonly` setting the value independently of this directive.

#### An explanation why I'm not simply binding to a scope variable

While I really appreciate Thomas' answer, I disagree with this part:

> Again, I highly recommend that you simply bind to a scope variable instead of checking for the presence of a class further up the tree.

I really find it both complicated and error-prone: I'm having a big form in which many fields already have their `readonly` logic (e.g., bank name is read only when a known BIC is entered). Now, I'd have to add `is_readonly` to all existing `ng-readonly` directives and add the directive to every `input` field missing it.

Moreover, the form includes some partials, which have no idea about the outer scope. Again, I'd have to add change the partial as above and make it to get `is_readonly` from the outer scope.

Comment: I haven't worked with angular, so I can't read this syntax, but +1 for a simple, well explained review request.

Comment: `org` is undefined

Comment: @PierreMenard Fixed, sorry for that.

Comment: Partials can access outer scope. `ng-include` creates a new child scope for the included fragment. Also, instead of having `ng-readonly` interrogate scope variables directly, have it call a function on your scope. Then you can have arbitrarily complicated logic without encoding it in your templates.

Comment: I came back to say much of what is in Thomas's answer.  Doing the work in a $watch seems un-idiomatic and non-performant.  The readonly class is being applied based on a model update, you should hook into that.

Comment: @Thomas Partials can access outer scope, but `address` should know nothing about being used inside of `customerDetails` as `deliveryAddress` which (unlike the `invoiceAddress`) gets readonly after delivery confirmatiom. My goal is to be able to use sub-forms without touching them at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally speaking, you should avoid looking outside the current directive for anything that would affect your internal state (bar events). The preferred method of communication is scopes. Here is how I would recommend you do this.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div>
        <input ng-readonly="is_readonly" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <input ng-readonly="is_readonly" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Simply toggling `$scope.is_readonly` from `MyCtrl` is enough to disable all child inputs that have `ng-readonly="is_readonly"`, and it's bindable too, so you can add/remove readonly status at runtime.

Now, if there is a genuine need to have the behaviour you described, then you have 2 options.

1. Stick with your current implementation, but this will **not** be performant, since your DOM traversal will fire any time the scope changes, for any reason, anywhere up the scope tree.
2. Rewrite to use directive's `require` property.

Here is how you would do the latter.

```
.directive("readonly", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "C",
        link: function() {},
        controller: function() {},
    }
})
.directive("input", function()
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        // search for optional parent directive named `readonly`
        require: "^?readonly",
        // 4th parameter is `readonly` controller or null.
        link: function($scope, element, attr, has_readonly) {
            var org = attr.ngReadonly;
            if (org) {
                return; // readonly seems to be set manually, so let's not touch it
            } else if (has_readonly) {
                attr.$set("readonly", true)
            }
        },
    };
})
```

This tells angular that it should pass you a reference to the readonly controller if found, or null otherwise. In this way, you can tell at link time whether the parent node exists. This saves you from performing the DOM traversal yourself, and should be faster too.

Again, I highly recommend that you simply bind to a scope variable instead of checking for the presence of a class further up the tree.

Comment: I disagree with the scope variable proposal (see my updated question), but I like the idea using `require`. I'll try to get it working.

Comment: I couldn't get it working and now I know why: At the enclosing element, I'm using `ng-readonly` which adds the `readonly` attribute later. And I know now, why I don't like using a scope variable: There are two parts of the form, each of them dependent on its own expression. Expressing this in the DOM is trivial, expressing it on every input is ugly, and having two different `$scope.is_readonly` would be even uglier. But maybe creating a scope for each part is the way to go?